# Splitting an Array in Matlab

Tags: matlab, csv, plot

I am working on this project and my goal is to plot the BPM per second on a graph and change the color of the graph from point to point.

I have a CSV file with Data and at this moment I am able to graph the BPM vs time graph. However, my next objective is to change the color of this graph for different regions.

I have defined the LED colors in the CSV file as a-red, b-green, c-yellow and d- blue. Sample data is as follows:

Seconds BPM LED
1 64 a
2 140 c
3 162 d
4 110 b
5 112 b
6 145 c
7 146 c
8 149 c
9 145 c
10 60 a

This is the code I currently have that graphs BPM vs Time. Now I have to change the color based on LED letters in my CSV file.

```
ftoread = 'DATALOG.CSV';
fid = fopen(ftoread); %OPENS the CSV file
data = textscan(fid,'%f%f%f%c','Headerlines',1,'Delimiter',',');
fclose(fid); % closes the file

Time = data{1}; %Time variables moved to new variable called x
BPM = data{2};% Readings moved to variable y
LED= data{3};

plot(Time,BPM, 'r'); % plot bp readings vs time

xlabel('Time of Reading');

ylabel('Blood Pressure Reading & Speed');

title('Blood Pressure Readings vs Time');
```

Comment: check out [Scatter](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/scatter.html). (examples do what you wanted, just change a,b,c,d doing into values)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you dont want to use scatter, you can do this

```
LED = [1 3 4 2 2 3 3 3 3 1];
colors = ['r', 'g', 'b', 'y']; % A color for each LED
Time = [1:10];
BPM = [64 140 162 119 112 145 146 149 145 60];
figure; hold all;

i = 1;
j = 2;
last_LED = LED(i);
for j=2:numel(LED)
    if LED(j) ~= last_LED
        plot(Time(i:j), BPM(i:j), colors(last_LED));
        last_LED = LED(j);
        i = j;
    end
end
```

Comment: thank you very much it worked. I just made a few adjustments since i had the data stored in a array. Also now i am running into a problem of adding a legend in the script. I did this legend('r','y','b','y');. However, the colors dont match any way of doing this?